# Помогите разобраться в работе функции

Tags: javascript

При каждом вызове функции она увеличивает аргумент на 1. Можно ли как-то реализовать это без вызова второй функции внутри? Не совсем мне ясна логика, почему с функцией внутри код работает, но если её убрать выводится только переданное значение.

```
function Counter(number) {
    return function () {
        return ++number;
    };
}

var f1 = Counter(0);
console.log(f1());
console.log(f1());
console.log(f1());
console.log(f1());
```

Comment: В `f1` вы сохранили внутренюю функцию при том, что `number` передали 0. Т.к. `f1` на протяжении кода Вы не меняете значение `f1`, там все еще находиться эта функция с числом. Вот и с каждым разом Вы увеличиваете `number` и возвращаете его и выводите на экран.

Comment: почитайте про замыкание и контекст выполнения функции, на собеседовании спросят

Comment: т.е. значение к примеру 1 сохраняется все время внутри  function() и передается потом в Counter(number) А если я вызову её повторно, то у меня уже в funcion() хранится 1, которую функция превратит в 2 и сохранит опять же внутри function() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это называется [замыкание](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#:%7E:text=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%E2%80%94%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%B8,%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F%20%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F.)

```
function Counter(number) {
    return function () {
        return ++number;
    };
}

var f1 = Counter(0);
console.log(f1());
console.log(f1());
console.log(f1());
console.log(f1());
```

вызов Counter(0) возвращает функцию которая замкнула в себе переменную number.

Если вы знакомы с OOП то можно произвести аналогию с классами и объектами

```
function Counter(number) {
    return function () {
        return ++number;
    };
}
```

это что-то подобие

```
class Counter{
    Counter(number) { // конструктор класса Counter
      this._number = number;
    }

    someMethod: function () { // метод по умолчанию
        return ++ this._number;
    };
}
```

что в свою очередь

```
var f1 = Counter(0);
console.log(f1());
```

это

```
var f1 = new Counter(0); // вызов конструктора Counter
console.log(f1.someMethod()); // вызов someMethod объекта f1
```

**PS.** Это аналогия только для тех кто знаком с ооп. На самом деле в JS как раз таки наоборот объекты и классы часто представляют через замыкания.